# Details not saving

Tags: contacts, upgrade, fields

I use Civi daily. When I speak to a contact, I will often go into Civi and update their details. Lately, this information has not been saving. For example, yesterday I entered two peoples' job titles. After doing so, I received a message saying the information had been saved. I went back into Civi this morning and the information is not there. Could anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Do you have lots of custom fields?

Comment: None that I am aware of. I don't have admin access to the database so I am not really sure.

Comment: I will try to find out whether we do have many custom fields and get back to you.

Comment: Pradeep. We have about 30 custom fields. I am entering the data into the Job Title, which is not saving.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see apache or nginx error log? Probably you may need to increase [post_max_size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size).